# Need help setting up editing template

Tags: templates, mediawiki, editing

I have just started working on a wiki where I want registered users to be able to post stuff. I want to have a link on the site which says something along the lines of 
"`Create new Entry`" which when clicked will take the user to an editing template. When the user is done filling in his information and clicks the save button I want that information to be saved in an own page. 
My question: What is the approach to achieving something like this?

```
tag:MediaWiki   1.19.2
PHP 5.3.14 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.1.63-0+squeeze1-log
```

Comment: What do you mean by "editing template"? A wizard? Or just a pre-loaded, unfilled template?

Comment: I was thinking of a pre-loaded unfilled template. with stuff on it such as: title of the page, different content sections and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [MultiBoilerplate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiBoilerplate) for this. This extension is very useful because users can select from a drop down list of templates for various pages which can contain default text which users themselves can define.

Tip: if you use the option:

```
$wgMultiBoilerplateOptions = false;
```

in `LocalSettings.php` then administrators can add new templates *via the wiki* (so without having to change any configurations in php).

Answer (score 1):

There are many [URL parameters for editing pages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Edit_and_submit) which can do what you want, especially [affecting the edit form](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_index.php#Options_affecting_the_edit_form). There is also an explicit [Manual on creating pages with preloaded text](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aCreating_pages_with_preloaded_text), which includes a list of helpful extensions to do such tasks.

Comment: Ok i will look through this and see if i can figure out how to do what im trying to do. Thanks